# How do i call a js function on pressing enter key

Tags: javascript

I'd like to know how I can initiate a javacsript function when pressing the enter key. I'm trying to create a function called `handleEnter(event, fn)`.

I want to use the function on an input field eg:

```
onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, update_field(this));
```

Answer (score 6):

For your function called onkeypress, check the event's .keyCode or .which value, and see if it is equal to 13.

```
function handleEnter(e, func){
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == 13)
        //Enter was pressed, handle it here
}
```

IIRC, IE uses event.which, and Firefox will use e.keyCode to see which key was pressed.

Comment: You can't use `function` as a parameter name or variable name in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**I think I've solved it.**

On the input field I've got:

```
<input onkeypress="return handleEnter(event, update_field, this, 'task');" type="text" />
```

**For my function I've got:**

```
function handleEnter(e, callback, obj, field){

    if(e){
        e = e
    } else {
        e = window.event
    }

    if(e.which){
    var keycode = e.which
    } else {
    var keycode = e.keyCode
    }


    if(keycode == 13) {
        var tstid = $(obj).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val();
        callback.apply(this, [field, $(obj).val(), tstid ]);
    }
}
```

and it seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this shorthand

```
<input type=”text” onKeydown=”Javascript: if (event.keyCode==13) Search();”>

<input type=”button” value=”Search” onClick=”Search();”>
```

From http://www.techtamasha.com/call-javascript-function-on-pressing-enter-key/25